# How to cast a string into an array using Yup

Tags: javascript, node.js, yup

So whenever I receive a string I want to store it as an array. But I've got no luck so far, i tried to do with cast and with transform. I just need some clarity to get the things going.

Is transform and cast the same thing? How to cast a string into an array using Yup?

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
        types: yup
           .array('type must be an array.')
           .of(
                yup
                   .string('the array must contains only strings.')
                   .transform(value =>
                      typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof 'string'
                           ? [value]
                           : value,
                   )
                   .matches(/(writer|artist)/, null),
           )
           .min(1, 'Need to provide at least one type')
           .max(2, 'Can not provide more than two types'),
        name: yup
           .string('name must be a string.')
           .min(3, 'too short'),
      
    });

let obj = {
      name: 'Kentarou Kishima',
      types: 'artist',
}
//returns ValidationError
obj = schema.cast(obj, { stripUnknown: true });

//trying to just validate results in the same error
schema
        .validate(obj)
        .then(() => {     
              
            next();
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return something;
        });
```

*ValidationError: types must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `"artist"`)*

Edit:
I fixed minor typo btw.
Well, I removed the matches line and it keeps returning the same Error. So now I am thinking since it's receiving a string and not an array, when it goes into the transform function it is going to search for the array items to cast, but there's none because it got a string. So it's well likely that the transform function should be side-by-side with array() and not inside it.

The code looks like this now, but I'm still getting the Error with or without matches():

```
.array('types must be an array.')
        .of(
            yup
                .string('the array must contains only strings.')
                .matches(/(^writer$|^artist$)/) //I improved the regex pattern                
        )
        .transform(value =>
            typeof value === 'string' || value instanceof String
                ? [value]
                : value,
        )
        .min(1, 'Need to provide at least one type')
        .max(2, 'Can not provide more than two types'),
```

To make things clearer, these are the type of input I am expecting:

```
let obj = {
      name: 'Kentarou Kishima',
      types: 'artist', //should cast
      types: ['artist'], //should pass
      types: ['artist', 'writer'], //should pass

      types: '', //should reject
      types: ['something'], //should reject
      types: ['artist', 'something', 'writer'], //should reject
      types: ['artist', 'artist'], // should reject, but i will put a test() later on.  

}
```

Comment: You're transforming a string to an array containing that string, or passing an array along, but then you're trying to match a regular expression to an array, and returning `null` if the match fails. A regular expression cannot be matched to the array itself, only the strings inside it. See the [documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#stringmatchesregex-regex-message-string--function-schema) for this method. I believe moving the `matches()` call above the `transform()` would fix this.

Comment: btw ... whatever `yup` does, I doubt one/it can trick the native syntax ... thus ... `myVar instanceof 'string'` is wrong and should have raised a `Right-hand side ...`-`TypeError` ... if at all then please use the `instanceof` operator like this ... `myVar instanceof String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around with the documentation I found the answer. In this case is enough to use the  `ensure()` function, basically it will take anything that is not an array and put it into an array. After that, the `matches()` function will reject anything that does not follow the regex pattern.

```
yup
        .array('types must be an array.')        
        .of(
            yup
                .string('the array must contains only strings.')
                .matches(/(^writer$|^artist$)/)                
        )
        .ensure()
        .min(1, 'Need to provide at least one type')
        .max(2, 'Can not provide more than two types'),
```

Edit:
Just a disclaimer, the way it is with `min(1)` enabled, this property always will be required even though there's no `required()`, even specifying `notRequired()` in the object doesn't do the trick.

This is a known issue in yup
https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1267

In my case, I need this validator for my POST (all required) and PUT (at least one required) requests, in POST requests I use it the way it is, in PUT requests I dynamically add the rules checking for those present in the req.body.

Answer (score 0):

The order of operations on the `types` property is out of order. It follows:

1. Ensure array element is string.
2. If the value is a string, convert it to an array containing itself.
3. If the array of the single string matches the regular expression, continue. If it does not, report `null`.

If you truly want an array of single-element arrays, then you can keep the transform, but you'll want to move the `matches()` above the `transform()` as the arrays that result from the `transform()` will never match the regular expression, and so `matches()` always returns your `null`.

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
        types: yup
           .array('type must be an array.')
           .of(
                yup
                   .string('the array must contains only strings.')
                   .matches(/(writer|artist)/, null)
                   .transform(value =>
                      typeof value === 'string' || myVar instanceof 'string'
                           ? [value]
                           : value,
                   ),
           )
           .min(1, 'Need to provide at least one type')
           .max(2, 'Can not provide more than two types'),
        name: yup
           .string('name must be a string.')
           .min(3, 'too short'),
      
    });
```

Comment: I switched the order and I even removed the matches() line, it keeps returning the same error. I updated my question.